# Favorites Shortcut in Oracle-SQLDeveloper?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, shortcut

this is a missing feature of Oracle SQL-Devlopper i am still searching for days.
-create a shortucut, or button, in fact a quick way to access the most used tables (of hundreds) of my DataBase.

I 've used Toad for years, and it's "favorites objects management" was a very important time saver feature . But now, on my new projet we have no choice and we have to use Oracle-SqlDeveloper :(:(

Can we manage favorites nativly in SQLDevelopper ? Or by using a third party add-on ?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this currently; [this](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/04/oracle-sql-developer-database-object-shortcuts/) or [this](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/09/search-and-browse-database-objects-with-oracle-sql-developer/) might help a little. Asking for a third-party add-on is off-topic. As a feature request you can [ask on the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)) perhaps.

Comment: Or [Making Your Own Custom Object Navigators](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/11/making-your-own-custom-object-navigators/)...

Comment: you can also just type the object you want to go to, and use ctrl-click to navigate to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no 'favorites' feature in SQL Developer. However, you can create reports that would give you what you want.

[Making Your Own Custom Object Navigators](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/11/making-your-own-custom-object-navigators/)

[image]

Comment: once you click on the object name, you get a fully-functional object editor. use the report to get to the object where you can do everything